# Arduino does not always receive message from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno which in the Arduino IDE runs code which should receive a message from Visual Studio via Serial Port. If the message is "ON" then lights are on if the message is "OF" then the lights are off.

Sometime it works but sometimes it does not and I don't understand why that is the case.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
   if (Serial.available())
   {
   
    
    message = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');// reading the message from c#

    
    
    if (message == "ON") // if message is on we go to hazard mode
    {
      state = 1;
      alarmOn = true;
    }
    else if ( message == "OFF") // otherwise we are in the normal mode
    {
      led_state = LOW;
      state = 0;
      alarmOn = false;
    }
  }
```

Here is my code from Visual Studio

```
            toggleLEd = !toggleLEd;
            string text = string.Empty;
            if (toggleLEd == true)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine("ON");
                Console.WriteLine("ON");
                text = "AlarmOn";
                lbDisplay.Items.Add(text);
            }
            else if(toggleLEd==false)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine("OFF");
                Console.WriteLine("OFF");
                text = "AlarmOff";
                lbDisplay.Items.Add(text);

            }
```

Comment: Are you able to log on arduinos side?  What if `Serial.available() == false`?  And what about your `led_sate = LOW;`, you never set it to another state when `message == "ON"`

Comment: @nilsK I tried it, does not work.

Comment: What does not work? Is the `Serial.available()` criteria always true? Are both not working, i.e. turning off / turning on or just one of them? Is your calling method not working or the arduino receiver? Please describe your problem more precisely. Please edit your question for this.

Comment: Serial.available() is always true but sometimes when the lights are they won't go off if the message is off and vice versa

Comment: Did you try to swap the serial cable?

Answer (score 0):

1. is the data transfer rate the same?
2. are you checking whether the port is open?
   serialPort1.WriteLine("OFF");
3. add it to the Arduino script Serial.println(message);
   read in VS from serial port and it will be clear to you whether the message was delivered or not

Comment: The port is open and message is delivered.

Comment: Arduino: byte incomingByte = Serial.read();
    
    if (incomingByte == '0')
    {
    }
    else if (incomingByte == '1')    
    {
   
    }
    VS: 
     var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes('1');
   _currentPort.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);